# Argument in operator << of class basic__ostream

Tags: c++, cout

```
operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
```

I see that class basic__ostream receive a function pointer following the above signature.
What is __ostream_type?

Comment: Handy reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2

Comment: `__ostream_type` is an implementation defined type, but that overload of `std::ostream<...>::operator<<` is likely used to implement IO manipulators like `std::endl`, `std::hex`, `std::oct`, `std::uppercase`, etc.. Look at the 10-12 overloads [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).